# I keep getting undefined from node js express post request body

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, body-parser

I try to make to get post req.body value but I keep getting undefined when I console.log I am using ( "express": "^4.17.1", )
I tried without body-parser and with body-parser, I keep getting the same result
I tried all solutions available in StackOverflow but I keep getting the same result as you can see in the server.js

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const _ = require("lodash");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
//app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
//var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(cors());


app.get("/", (req, res) => 
{
    res.send("Hello");
});

app.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    // const username = req.body.username;
    // const  password  = req.body.password;
    const {username , password } = req.body;
    console.log("username : " + username);
    console.log(req.body);
    res.json(username);
});



let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 5000;
}

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Server has started Successfully at port " + port);
});
```

and this is the postman request

> localhost:5000/login?username="salem"&password=1234567

and bellow the package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Salem",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.2"
  }
}
```

I hope this gives a clear idea about my issue

Best Regards
Salem

Comment: you're not sending a request body in postman - URI search value is not a request body

Comment: ```curl --location --request POST 'localhost:5000/login' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "username": "salem",
    "password": "1234567"
}'```
Use this payload, you get the data in body. Currently you are passing the data as query param, that can only be accessed by req.query. To access data from body, you need to pass it in the body as shown in the above payload.

Comment: everything you put after ? (question mark) can be accessed through params of request object, Query params used for get methods not for post method. So you better pass username and password from body form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing data as Query Parameters

> localhost:5000/login?username="salem"&password=1234567

but fetching value from the req.body

> const {username , password } = req.body;

**What you should use is :**

```
var username = req.query.username;
var password = req.query.password;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the user details to the body from the postman or you can use the query object to retrieve the same from the URL.

see [req.query](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query)